# Auto position nodes in statechart in GOJS

Tags: gojs, statechart

I want to have "loc" value (positioning value  eg. loc = "10 10") automatically calculated for statechart according to number of nodes in GOJS. Is there any specific attributes or commands to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [Diagram.layout](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#layout) to an instance of [ForceDirectedLayout](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/ForceDirectedLayout.html).

So just add this line to the initialization of the Diagram in StateChart.html:

```
layout: $(go.ForceDirectedLayout),
```

Depending on when you want a layout to happen, you might be interested in setting [Layout.isInitial](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Layout.html#isInitial) to false and/or setting [Layout.isOngoing](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Layout.html#isOngoing) to false.  Read more at the [Introduction to Layouts](http://gojs.net/latest/intro/layouts.html) page.

Answer (score 2):

GoJS has the concept of [Layouts](http://gojs.net/latest/intro/layouts.html) for automatic Node and Link positioning.

It is possible to create your own layouts that position the nodes based on custom criteria. There is an intro to making your own layouts [here](http://gojs.net/latest/intro/extensions.html) and examples in the [extensions gallery](http://gojs.net/latest/extensions/Fishbone.html).

Comment: Thanks Simon, Your answer was also very helpful for me, but I got the exact answer (code syntax) from 'Walter Northwoods'.